# Is there a good resource for Mandarin or Cantonese terms for motorsports and motorsports news?

Tags: resources

I am a big Formula 1 fan so I would love to add some motorsports-specific terms to my studying. Simple things such as "race car" to maybe more complex terms like "slipstream" or "pit stop". Even just a short list of the terms people actually use colloquially when referring to motorsports would be great.

I would also love to know if anyone is familiar with any particularly popular Chinese motorsports news sites or blogs?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

赛车网：https://cn.motorsport.com/

虎扑社区 - F1赛车场：https://bbs.hupu.com/f1

赛道时光：http://circday.com/

SRFC模拟赛车网：http://bbs.srfc.com.cn/

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @wickedfable Glad to hear that. Could you help to upvote and accept the answer please?

Comment: Sorry, just did it now! I didn't realize about being able to choose an answer. However, I did try upvoting before but got a warning about new accounts not recording upvotes. Looks like it's fine, now, though. Thank you, in any case!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your level of language, but if you're at anything like my (low) level you might consider checking out children's shows and then episodes involving cars. You'll learn it in the context of the rest of the episode which I think is better than trying to memorize a list of isolated words. And sometimes they'll surprise you and throw in some relatively advanced vocab like this exchange on an unrelated peppa pig episode （小宝宝亚历山大）:

猪爸爸： 这婴儿车看上去真不错！ (Daddy pig: Hey, nice stroller!)

猪伯伯： 当然。 五档调速，挡泥板， 还有防抱死制动系统！ (Uncle Pig: Of course. it has five gears, mud flaps, and an anti-lock braking system!)

佩奇： 完全听不懂。。。 (Peppa: I did not understand that at all).

Comment: That's not a bad idea - I hadn't really thought of that, honestly. I think my main issue is just not knowing where to go for Chinese motorsports content and also having no way to learn about it other than looking up individual words that might not necessarily be the ones people actual use in this context. But yeah, maybe something like if there's a Mandarin version of the Cars films by Pixar wouldn't be a terrible place to start.

Comment: Cars films sounds like a good idea. Work through it and understand every word however long it takes, and by the time you finish you will know it by heart.